# Perl trapping Ctrl-C with threads in bash

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl, bash, sigint

While I see how to have [Perl trap Ctrl-C (sigint) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512317/perl-trapping-ctrl-c-sigint-in-bash); I'm getting lost at why does it fail with threads; I'm trying the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use threads;
use threads::shared; # for shared variables

my $cnt :shared = 0;

sub counter() {
  while (1) {
    $cnt++;
    print "thread: $cnt \n";
    sleep 1;
  }
}

sub finisher{
  ### Thread exit! ...
  print "IIII";
  threads->exit();
  die;
};

# any of these will cause stop of reaction to Ctrl-C
$SIG{INT} = \&finisher;
$SIG{INT} = sub {print "EEE\n" ;} ;
$SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';

# setting to DEFAULT, brings usual behavior back
#~ $SIG{INT} = 'DEFAULT';

my $mthr = threads->create(\&counter);
$mthr->join();
```

... and as soon as the SIGINT handler is set to anything else than the default (*where Ctrl-C causes exit*), it basically causes for the script to stop reacting on Ctrl-C any longer:

```
$ ./test.pl 
thread: 1 
^Cthread: 2 
^C^Cthread: 3 
^C^C^C^Cthread: 4 
thread: 5 
thread: 6 
thread: 7 
thread: 8 
Terminated
```

... and I have to `sudo killall perl` in order to terminate the script.

There is a bit on threads and Ctrl-C in these links:

- [Sending sig INT ( control C ) to threads - Dev Shed](http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/sending-sig-int-control-c-to-threads-413317.html)
- [SOLVED: Is this a bug of perl threads ? - Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=828184)
- [How do we capture CTRL ^ C - Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=436492)
- [Is the signal handler supposed to work like this?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=707861)

... but I cannot say if it conclusively answers whether "capturing" Ctrl-C under perl in bash is definitely impossible?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

---

Ok, I think I got it (*but I'm leaving the previous entry (below) for reference ...*)

The trick turns out to be that, from the main SIGINT handler, one must signal the thread via `kill` - AND then thread also needs to have a separate SIGINT handler (from the first link in OP); AND instead of just `join()`, one needs to use the code in the [answer by @ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534566/perl-trapping-ctrl-c-with-threads-in-bash/7534771#7534771):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use threads;
use threads::shared; # for shared variables

my $cnt :shared = 0;
my $toexit :shared = 0;


sub counter() {
  $SIG{'INT'} = sub { print "Thread exit\n"; threads->exit(); };
  my $lexit = 0;
  while (not($lexit)) {
    { lock($toexit);
    $lexit = $toexit;
    }
    $cnt++;
    print "thread: $cnt \n";
    sleep 1;
  }
  print "out\n";
}

my $mthr;

sub finisher{
  { lock($toexit);
  $toexit = 1;
  }
  $mthr->kill('INT');
};

$SIG{INT} = \&finisher;

$mthr = threads->create(\&counter);


print "prejoin\n";
#~ $mthr->join();

while (threads->list()) {
   my @joinable = threads->list(threads::joinable);
   if (@joinable) {
      $_->join for @joinable;
   } else {
      sleep(0.050);
   }
}
print "postjoin\n";
```

I may be overkilling it with the `$toexit` there, but at least now this is the result:

```
$ ./test.pl
prejoin
thread: 1 
thread: 2 
thread: 3 
^CThread exit
postjoin
```

Many thanks to all for the solution :)
Cheers!

---

Thanks to the suggestion by @mob for `PERL_SIGNALS` to `unsafe` (*note, [Perl 5.14 does not allow "internal" setting of $ENV{'PERL_SIGNALS'}](http://groups.google.com/group/perl.perl5.porters/browse_thread/thread/7cd25dcb2661ed67/3eeb441f1ce3e959?lnk=raot)*), I'm getting somewhere - now Ctrl-C is detected - but it either terminates with a segfault, or with error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use threads;
use threads::shared; # for shared variables

my $cnt :shared = 0;
my $toexit :shared = 0;

sub counter() {
  my $lexit = 0;
  while (not($lexit)) {
    { lock($toexit);
    $lexit = $toexit;
    }
    $cnt++;
    print "thread: $cnt \n";
    sleep 1;
  }
  print "out\n";
  #~ threads->detach(); # Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Cannot detach a joined thread
  #~ exit;
}

my $mthr;

# [http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl5-porters/164923/ [perl #92246] Perl 5.14 does not allow "internal" setting of $ENV ...]
sub finisher{
  ### Thread exit! ...
  #~ print "IIII";
  # anything here results with: Perl exited with active threads:
  #~ threads->exit();
  #~ threads->join();
  #~ $mthr->exit();
  #~ $mthr->join();
  #~ $mthr->detach();
  #~ $mthr->kill();
  #~ threads->exit() if threads->can('exit');   # Thread friendly
  #~ die;
  { lock($toexit);
  $toexit = 1;
  }
  #~ threads->join(); #
};




# any of these will cause stop of reaction to Ctrl-C
$SIG{INT} = \&finisher;
#~ $SIG{INT} = sub {print "EEE\n" ; die; } ;
#~ $SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';

# setting to DEFAULT, brings usual behavior back
#~ $SIG{INT} = 'DEFAULT';

$mthr = threads->create(\&counter);
print "prejoin\n";
$mthr->join();
print "postjoin\n";
```

With the comments as above, that code react with:

```
$ PERL_SIGNALS="unsafe" ./testloop06.pl
prejoin
thread: 1 
thread: 2 
thread: 3 
^Cthread: 4 
out
Segmentation fault
```

Result is the same if I add the following that uses [Perl::Signals::Unsafe](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Signals::Unsafe):

```
$mthr = threads->create(\&counter);

UNSAFE_SIGNALS {
  $mthr->join();
};
```

Almost there, hopefully someone can chime in ... :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435539/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signal handlers are only called between Perl opcodes. Your code is blocked in `$mthr->join();`, so it never gets to handle the signal.

Possible solution:

```
use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );

# Interruptable << $_->join() for threads->list; >>
while (threads->list()) {
   my @joinable = threads->list(threads::joinable);
   if (@joinable) {
      $_->join for @joinable;
   } else {
      sleep(0.050);
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @ikegami - I see what the problem is now. Cheers!

Comment: Set the environment variable `PERL_SIGNALS` to `unsafe`, or see [`Perl::Signals::Unsafe`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Signals::Unsafe) for a workaround.

Comment: No, really don't do what @mob suggests. Find another way.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, @mob - I have posted an example of that below, but its segfaulting or generating errors...

Comment: @sdaau, Added possible solution.

Comment: @ikegami - I really hope someone can point to an alternative; otherwise everything I'm finding gives no results, as my posts here show :) Thanks - cheers!

Comment: Many, many thanks for your edit, @ikegami - thanks to it, I now have a code that finally works, which is posted in my answer below... Cheers!